# Azure CDN (Standard Microsoft) - IP addresses of servers

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-cdn

We are using an **Azure CDN with pricing tier Standard Microsoft**. It's using our site as a "custom origin" so we need to make sure that the CDN server has access to this site.

My question is: **what are the IP addresses that this CDN server could use?**
(And therefore, we should add to our whitelist.)

I have found this link, but it applies only to Verizon servers, not to "Standard Microsoft" servers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-pop-list-api

I also found this list of Microsoft Azure Datacenter IP Ranges, but it doesn't seem to be the appropriate list either:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41653

A third thing that we tried, is using Azure's "Service Tag" source with "AzureCloud.WestEurope" in our NSG, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Unfortunately, Azure CDN from Standard Microsoft has not disclosed the POP IP address, currently. It seems that POP location gradually expands more regions. Refer to this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-locations-for-azure-cdn-now-available/). These POP edge sites location is not exactly the same as the Azure datacenter location.

[image]

If you want to improve this, you could request your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) or upvote [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/35703616-cdn). Alternatively, you also could [create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Comment: The "Azure CDN for Microsoft" link only shows IP addresses for Verizon servers. We are using "Standard Microsoft" so this list doesn't apply.

The "Azure datacenter IP" list could theoretically apply, but it seems it doesn't. From a test with temporarily disabling our IP whitelisting, I found that the IP address 147.243.66.234 was used by the Azure CDN. This is not in any of the ranges mentioned in the "Azure datacenter IP" list.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the useful links!
Apart from the suggestion link that you mentioned, I also added this suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169397-cdn/suggestions/37051585-publicize-the-ip-addresses-of-microsoft-cdn-server

Comment: gladly help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Azure CDN from Microsoft's IPv4 backend IP space: 147.243.0.0/16

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-pop-list-api

Comment: Excellent! The CIDR appears to work with the 'Standard Microsoft' SKU, even thought the link talks about the Verizon SKUs.

Comment: I think the place to find the current list of IP ranges is to download this document, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519  There is a section in the JSON for "AzureFrontDoor.Frontend" which I think MIGHT be the IP addresses clients would see CDN content come from in their browsers.  I can tell you I tested a CDN property we host in Azure CDN, and the IP it originated from is in one of those CIDRs.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not available yet. Only Verizon and Akami were the old CDN providers and they are available. For the latest updates, I would recommend opening a support ticket with our Microsoft Azure Storage and CDN team. They will have a crisp answer and about it's availability.