# Can't access CDN while storage account is ip restricted?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I setup my Azure storage endpoint and added internal ip address ranges to the firewalls and virtual networks.  I setup a cdn endpoint and am not able to access the content from the CDN url.  I am able to access the content from the storage url.  When I remove the ip restrictions, the CDN url starts working.  Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled firewall of Azure Storage Account, you need to whitelist the outbound CDN IP address to this firewall, then you can access the content from the CDN URL since these POP servers make requests to origin servers that are associated with Azure Content Delivery Network (CDN) endpoints.

Currently, you could use the REST API to retrieve the set of IPs for **Verizon**’s point of presence (POP) servers. see [Edge Nodes - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cdn/edgenodes/list) for (Azure CDN Standard from Verizon or Azure CDN Premium from Verizon). To ensure that you have the latest POP list, retrieve it at least once a day.

However, unfortunately, Azure CDN from Standard Microsoft has not disclosed the POP IP address. See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040242/azure-cdn-standard-microsoft-ip-addresses-of-servers).

So far, It seems that you'd better to use Azure CDN from Verizon to restrict the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me, even though I'm using the 'Standard Microsoft' SKU and the linked document appears to talk about the Verizon SKUs.

Azure CDN from Microsoft's IPv4 backend IP space: 147.243.0.0/16

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-pop-list-api

When I observed the list of IP addresses rejected due to IP address restrictions, I found the following IPs, which match the CIDR.

[image]